# Dynamic TabControl in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol, tabitem

I started using WPF (in C#) some weeks ago and now i need help for some advanced use of tabcontrol.

Fisrt of all, I'm using a MVVM (Model View ViewModel) pattern for designing my application, and I have a constraint that is to try to not add code in code behind file (that inititalise xaml files).

Now my issue is to create dynamically new tabItems in my MainWindow View (Window) that shows an instance of my Detail View (Page) when I click on a button ("New Tab" button for example).

I have found a lot off stuff about dynamic creation off tabitem on the web but often with modifications in code behind files. I though using binding but I don't know how can I use binding to this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVVM will help you out.

Create a ViewModel for your MainWindow View. There you can have a collection
of DetailViewModels. Just use an `ObservableCollection` of DetailViewModels here.

In your View, bind the `ItemsSource` of the `TabControl` to that Collection.

Your AddTab Button can have a Command Binding. That Command can be a `ICommand`
derived class, that is published in the MainWindowViewModel. Pressing the button
then ends up in the MainWindow ViewModel, adding another DetailViewModel and
updating the View that way.

Have a look to this excellent video tuturial on MVVM here: [Jason Dollinger on MVVM](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650)

He explains how that can be made, with examples for Main and Detail ViewModel
and commands.

The sourcecode that he develops in his video is available here: [Sourcecode on Lab49](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2689)

Perhaps it even easier for you to create a ViewModel that is just used
by the `TabControl`. Set the `DataContext` of the `TabControl` to that 
TabControlViewModel then. Publish that TabControlViewModel in your 
MainWindowViewModel as a public property, to accomplish that.

Your code-behind will be empty, except some InitializeComponent perhaps.

Comment: And What did you use for binding ? Dependency properties or INotifyPropertychanged. Personnaly I use the second one for the moment in my project but i still don't know which is better.

Comment: Whenever possible I use `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Well i've done the modifications in my code and it's works great. When i clic on the new tab button, a new tab appear but in this tab I don't see my detail view but a text line with the name of my detailViewModel. I though I've forgot the datacontext in my DetailView but no. So i don't know. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: What should your DetailView look like? At the moment I have no idea either.

Comment: My DetailView is some kind of form. A grid with labels and textFields and a button.

Comment: I think i find the problem. The dataContext of my detailView point on the detailViewModel class and maybe i have to point to one of the detailViewModel which are in the ObservableCollection in my mainWindowViewModel.

Comment: Unfortunately, the whole blog.lab49.com domain is not available any more and all links redirect to a 404 at www.lab49.com.

Comment: Fortunately, you can google for "Jason Dollinger on MVVM" and get the video (haven't seen the source code anywhere though).

Answer (score 2):

Great [set](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38030/WPF-If-Carlsberg-did-MVVM-Frameworks-Part-1-of-n) of articles about MVVM by Sacha Barber contains downloadable application where he expose they way of dynamic view creation using tab control. You can download demo application attached to article to see how to use dynamic tab control.
Example:

You need where you would bind collection of workspaces that represent data model for tab content and if needed addition properties for tab e.g. closable or not, disabled or not, Name and so on. This can be your ViewModelBase. Create you tab item template to support your view model.

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl"
                 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Workspaces}" 
                 Template="{StaticResource DynamicTabControlTemplate}">         
</TabControl>
```

Init collection of workspaces for example like this

> Workspaces = new ObservableCollection();

And after you adding new item to collection tab control will be changed too.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to `ItemsSource` property of a `TabControl` which represents collection of tab items. Then you can manipulate the collection from your ViewModel.